# the simplest way to change a time to particular timezone

Tags: java, android, time, timezone

there are two string

```
String date = "9/13/2012";
String time = "5:48pm";
```

the time is GMT+0, I wanna change it to GMT+8,what is the simplest way to change a time to particular timezone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Parse it using a `SimpleDateFormat` set to the UTC time zone
- Format the parsed `Date` value using a `SimpleDateFormat` set to the time zone you're interested in. (It's likely to be something other than just "UTC+8" - you should find out which TZDB time zone ID you *really* want.

For example:

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mma", Locale.US);
inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC");
Date date = inputFormat.parse(date + " " + time);

// Or whatever format you want...
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.US);
outputFormat.setTimeZone(targetTimeZone);
String outputText = outputFormat.format(date);
```

(If you can use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead, that'd be great - but I understand that it's pretty big for an Android app.)

Answer (score 1):

The Joda-Time library provides a good set of objects for working with dates/times in multiple time zones. http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Something like this for example:

```
    String date = "9/13/2012";
    String time = "5:48pm";

    String[] dateParts = date.split("/");
    Integer month = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[0]);
    Integer day = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[1]);
    Integer year = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[2]);

    String[] timeParts = time.split(":");
    Integer hour = Integer.parseInt(timeParts[0]);
    Integer minutes = Integer.parseInt(timeParts[1].substring(0,timeParts[1].lastIndexOf("p")));

    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minutes, DateTimeZone.forID("Etc/GMT"));
    dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Etc/GMT+8"));
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String date = "9/13/2012";
        String time = "5:48pm";

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u h:ma", Locale.UK);
        LocalDateTime ldtSource = LocalDateTime.parse(date + " " + time, dtf);

        OffsetDateTime odtSource = ldtSource.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        OffsetDateTime odtTarget = odtSource.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of("+08:00"));

        System.out.println(odtTarget);

        // In a custom format
        System.out.println(odtTarget.format(dtf));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2012-09-14T01:48+08:00
9/14/2012 1:48am
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/I2QlRX)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>